# Object Detection on Android with Tensorflow Lite

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow, object-detection, bounding-box

Trying to implement a **custom** object detection model with Tensorflow Lite, using Android Studio. I am following the guidance provided here: [Running on mobile with TensorFlow Lite](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_mobile_tensorflowlite.md), however with no success. The example model runs properly showing all the detected labels. Nonetheless, when I try with my custom model I am **not getting any labels** at all. I have also tried with other models(from the internet but the outcome is the same). It is like that the labels are not being passed with the write way. I copied my **detect.tflite** and **labelmap.txt**, I changed the *TF_OD_API_INPUT_SIZE* and the *TF_OD_API_IS_QUANTIZED* in the **DetectorActivity.java** but still not getting results(detected class with a bounding box and a score).

The **Logcat** shows the following:

```
2020-10-11 18:37:54.315 31681-31681/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection E/HAL: PATH3 /odm/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
2020-10-11 18:37:54.315 31681-31681/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection E/HAL: PATH2 /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
2020-10-11 18:37:54.315 31681-31681/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection E/HAL: PATH1 /system/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
2020-10-11 18:37:54.315 31681-31681/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection E/HAL: PATH3 /odm/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
2020-10-11 18:37:54.315 31681-31681/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection E/HAL: PATH2 /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
2020-10-11 18:37:54.315 31681-31681/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection E/HAL: PATH1 /system/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
2020-10-11 18:37:54.859 31681-31681/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection E/tensorflow: CameraActivity: Exception!
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: This model does not contain associated files, and is not a Zip file.
        at org.tensorflow.lite.support.metadata.MetadataExtractor.assertZipFile(MetadataExtractor.java:325)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.support.metadata.MetadataExtractor.getAssociatedFile(MetadataExtractor.java:165)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.tflite.TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.create(TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java:118)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.DetectorActivity.onPreviewSizeChosen(DetectorActivity.java:96)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.CameraActivity.onPreviewFrame(CameraActivity.java:200)
        at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:1157)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
```

How can I take the detection? Do I need an additional file(metadata) relative with the labels or I am doing sth else wrong?
The above case is tested with an Android 7 device. Thanks!

Comment: Have you got the issue solved . I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Yeah, the issue have been solved, taking into cosideration Gusthema's answer. I followed the instructions from the given (metadata) link, creating the metadata file and attaching it to the main model. This was enough to deal with the aforementioned errors and run succesfully my application. @KARUNESHPALEKAR

Comment: Can you please share the script that you used to generate metadata

Comment: Actually, I have added it as an answer to this question. You can find it down below. This was the trick that helped me: "subgraph.outputTensorMetadata = 4*[output_meta]". @KARUNESHPALEKAR

Comment: Did you use the json file at the end or tflite+metadata as the solution. And also how did you optimise the model , because the documentation speaks about optimisation of a keras model but there is no information on optimisation of a model created using object detection api

Comment: The json file is optional, in case you want to see the results. I cannot see any optimazation at my procedure. I use "export_tflite_ssd_graph.py" to get the frozen graph and then "TFLiteConverter" to convert my model to tflite, followed by the metadata steps. @KARUNESHPALEKAR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with this documentation specifically that wasn't updated.

The main problem is that the sample was updated to use models with [Metadata](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/metadata) attached to it, specifically with the labels embedded as an asset of the model.

When you add your labels file to the model, everything should just work.

Comment: Hi..I tried to make model with metadata..But, still no detection....The link to create metadata you gave is throwing error "output tensor should punch of the number output tensor metadate". Then i use [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64097085/issue-in-creating-tflite-model-populated-with-metadata-for-object-detection). Then, I was able to make TFlite with metadata. However, it still no detection.

Answer (score 1):

To better understand the suggested solution proposed by Gusthema, I provide you with the code that worked in my case:

```
pip install tflite-support

from tflite_support import flatbuffers
from tflite_support import metadata as _metadata
from tflite_support import metadata_schema_py_generated as _metadata_fb


# Creates model info.
model_meta = _metadata_fb.ModelMetadataT()
model_meta.name = "MobileNetV1 image classifier"
model_meta.description = ("Identify Unesco Monuments Route"
                          "image from a set of 18 categories")
model_meta.version = "v1"
model_meta.author = "TensorFlow"
model_meta.license = ("Apache License. Version 2.0 "
                      "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.")


# Creates input info.
input_meta = _metadata_fb.TensorMetadataT()

# Creates output info.
output_meta = _metadata_fb.TensorMetadataT()


input_meta.name = "image"
input_meta.description = (
    "Input image to be classified. The expected image is {0} x {1}, with "
    "three channels (red, blue, and green) per pixel. Each value in the "
    "tensor is a single byte between 0 and 255.".format(300, 300))
input_meta.content = _metadata_fb.ContentT()
input_meta.content.contentProperties = _metadata_fb.ImagePropertiesT()
input_meta.content.contentProperties.colorSpace = (
    _metadata_fb.ColorSpaceType.RGB)
input_meta.content.contentPropertiesType = (
    _metadata_fb.ContentProperties.ImageProperties)
input_normalization = _metadata_fb.ProcessUnitT()
input_normalization.optionsType = (
    _metadata_fb.ProcessUnitOptions.NormalizationOptions)
input_normalization.options = _metadata_fb.NormalizationOptionsT()
input_normalization.options.mean = [127.5]
input_normalization.options.std = [127.5]
input_meta.processUnits = [input_normalization]
input_stats = _metadata_fb.StatsT()
input_stats.max = [255]
input_stats.min = [0]
input_meta.stats = input_stats



# Creates output info.
output_meta = _metadata_fb.TensorMetadataT()
output_meta.name = "probability"
output_meta.description = "Probabilities of the 18 labels respectively."
output_meta.content = _metadata_fb.ContentT()
output_meta.content.content_properties = _metadata_fb.FeaturePropertiesT()
output_meta.content.contentPropertiesType = (
    _metadata_fb.ContentProperties.FeatureProperties)
output_stats = _metadata_fb.StatsT()
output_stats.max = [1.0]
output_stats.min = [0.0]
output_meta.stats = output_stats
label_file = _metadata_fb.AssociatedFileT()
label_file.name = os.path.basename('/content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research/deploy/labelmap.txt')
label_file.description = "Labels for objects that the model can recognize."
label_file.type = _metadata_fb.AssociatedFileType.TENSOR_AXIS_LABELS
output_meta.associatedFiles = [label_file]


# Creates subgraph info.
subgraph = _metadata_fb.SubGraphMetadataT()
subgraph.inputTensorMetadata = [input_meta]
subgraph.outputTensorMetadata = 4*[output_meta]
model_meta.subgraphMetadata = [subgraph]

b = flatbuffers.Builder(0)
b.Finish(
    model_meta.Pack(b),
    _metadata.MetadataPopulator.METADATA_FILE_IDENTIFIER)
metadata_buf = b.Output()


# metadata and the label file are written into the TFLite file
populator = _metadata.MetadataPopulator.with_model_file('/content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/exported_model/detect.tflite')
populator.load_metadata_buffer(metadata_buf)
populator.load_associated_files(['/content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research/deploy/labelmap.txt'])
populator.populate()
```

Eventually, if you want to create a json file to display the outcome(the metadata file) you can use:

```
displayer = _metadata.MetadataDisplayer.with_model_file('/content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/exported_model/detect.tflite')
export_json_file = os.path.join('/content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/exported_model',
                    os.path.splitext('detect.tflite')[0] + ".json")
json_file = displayer.get_metadata_json()
# Optional: write out the metadata as a json file
with open(export_json_file, "w") as f:
  f.write(json_file)
```

P.S.: Be careful to change the few parts of code, so as to be compatible with your needs. (e.g. if you are using images of 512x512 you have to alter it from the "input_meta.description" variable).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a regression there.
Could you try it with the following?

```
<at your TF example repo>
$ git checkout de42482b453de6f7b6488203b20e7eec61ee722e^
```