# How to use my custom model (tflite) to run in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I have followed the instructions from TensorFlow lite to create an object detection application on Android, and my tflite model was successfully run when I tested it on a laptop. But when I replace the tflite model from the example app with my tflite model, it can't detect anything.

Is there anything else I need to do? Please help me, I've been stuck in this situation for a week.

Comment: Are you sure the corresponding model is defined in Firebase?

Comment: This question need improvement. Please share your tflite-call code, data preprocessing and model if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou for the response. this case has been resolved. The real problem is that the model I'm using doesn't yet have metadata, so I have to run that metadata first.

Here's a [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64315799/object-detection-on-android-with-tensorflow-lite) for adding metadata.